# Borit karshina lAma he baa or lEma

Tags: tefilla, grammar-dikduk

A simple question on Nussach Hatefila. On the basis of Tosfot Yom tov

> מסכת ערלה פרק ב - משנה ו
>
> וּלְמָה אָמְרוּ כָּל הַמְחַמֵּץ וְהַמְתַבֵּל וְהַמְדַמֵּעַ לְהַחֲמִיר‏

See [Tosfot Yom Tov](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9685&st=&pgnum=231&hilite=) "והלמד שימושית והקריאה בשוא והמ"ם פתוחה...‏"
Pitum Haketoret

> בֹּרִית כַּרְשִׁינָה לָמָה הִיא בָאָה, כְּדֵי לְיַפּוֹת בָּהּ אֶת הַצִּפֹּרֶן, כְּדֵי שֶׁתְּהֵא נָאָה. יֵין קַפְרִיסִין לָמָה הוּא בָא כְּדֵי לִשְׁרוֹת בּוֹ אֶת הַצִּפֹּרֶן כְּדֵי שֶׁתְּהֵא עַזָּה, ‏

Why Lama (why) and not Lema (what is the purpose)?

 The same problematic exist with bema, bama/bame or kama kema
במרה כמה למה
Open question or multiple choice question. I think that the point is this. Borit karshina --> multiple choice question for which spice, which function --> Tsiporen... naa
Yayn Kafrisin --> m.c.q -->tsiporen ...aza

Answer (score 1):

In *Pitum HaKetoret*, the "למה" is the "regular" "למה", meaning "why". However, according to R' Ovadia from Bartenura, the "ולמה" in *Orla* means "ובמה", i.e. "in which case" (and **not** "and why"). Therefore, to explain how R' Ovadia's reading sits well with the text, the *Tosfot Yom Tov* explains that the "ולמה" isn't the "regular" "למה" (with a *kamatz* under the *lamed*), it's a "*lamed shimushit*", i.e. "ל-מה", meaning "for what purpose", or in our case, "in which case".

To clarify - both your suggestions would fit the text in *Pitum HaKetoret* (just like asking "why" vs "for what purpose"), but as mentioned above, that's not the distinction made by the *Tosfot Yom Tov* in *Orla*.

Comment: I having come up with this solution but after all my question is good. I just verified in Sepharadic Sidur, --> Lema

Comment: @kouty Indeed, that's why I added that second part - there really isn't a substantial difference between the two options, however in *Orla* the meaning is different from those two.

Comment: With Be Ba it is the same. Bame Madlikin Bama Isha iots'a. Or with Caf. Keitsas, Keeyze tsad. opened --> A. QUIZ---> E