# PTIJ - Who is Boris Karshina

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I have heard much about Boris Karshina, but cannot find any biographical information for him on the Internet (other than [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71069/borit-karshina-lama-he-baa-or-lema), where his name is misspelled).  Please help me!

Edit: Never mind, I found him [here on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/people/Boris-Karshina/100009793695456).  (Apparently my jokes are not original...)

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Help us out a bit. I see the linked question. But, please translate the Aramaic term, literally.

Comment: @DanF What Aramaic term?  It is about a Russian person, not anything Aramaic!

Comment: I'm willing to lose a point just to protest the allowance of these ridiculous questions, IMHO.

Comment: @DanF Purim Torah aside: *borit* means an alkaline cleanser; (you'll find the prophet talking about washing away their sins with *neter* and *borit*)  *karshinin* are a kind of bean usually used as animal feed, usually translated as "vetch." So it was some kind of alkaline solution made from these beans. Artscroll half-translates "Karshina lye"; R' Aryeh Kaplan says "vetch lye."

Comment: @Moses613 I asked the question because it inspires creativity, such as msh210's answer.  Here are a bunch of other similar questions, check out their vote totals: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80247/who-is-morris-ayin  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55622/who-is-this-lamar  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80688/who-is-herbert

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/131059

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He lives in Cabin 9, [In](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inia,_Paphos), Cyprus.

Comment: And like many random people on the Internet, don't believe anything that Boris says! It's almost certainly a lye and/or a k'vetch. In fact, everyone he's come into contact with winds up just shutting down conversations with *nuh-uh!*

Comment: @Shalom this would make more sense as a comment to Shmuel's answer below...  But excellent point!

Answer (score 6):

You could try asking him *[directly.](https://plus.google.com/112939553270665013111)*

Comment: Omg there's actually guy named this?

Comment: A simple google search revealed two such people. And yes, omg.

Comment: @ezra, Shmuel, not likely a real person.  It's just a google account for someone with that name.  See this facebook page as an illustration https://www.facebook.com/people/Boris-Karshina/100009793695456

Comment: Clearly that guy thought of this joke first.

Comment: @Shmuel, indeed, see the edit to my question.