# Where was Carshina? (Borit Carshina)

Tags: korbanos-ketores-prayers, location

I'm assuming that [Carshina](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Concluding_Prayers%2C_Korbanot_(Israel)%2C_Pitum_HaKetoret.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (as mentioned in Pitom HaKetores - פטום הקטורת) is a place, since the Ketores also mentions places like Cyprus, Sedom, Jordan.

Any idea where Carshina is/was?

Comment: There’s a place called Be’er Karshina in southern Israel today. Perhaps it’s in that general area.

Comment: @Chatzkel other way around! Be'er Karshina means "vetch well", as in there was a well there and a lot of vetch beans grew nearby.

Comment: @shalom see my comment to the answer of dov. Maybe that’s why the place was called that, but clearly there was such a place as rashi and other Rishonim say

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @Shalom said in the comments it is not the name of a region but rather a type of plant / bean.

Refer to the Jastrow [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Concluding_Prayers%2C_Korbanot_(Israel)%2C_Pitum_HaKetoret.1?lang=bi&p2=Jastrow%2C_%D7%9B%D6%B7%D6%BC%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%A9%D6%B4%D7%81%D7%99%D7%A0%D6%B8%D7%94_I&lang2=bi) with all the sources linked below:

> **I** כַּרְשִׁינָה, (כַּרְשִׁינָא II) f. (cmp. כְּרֵישָׁה) a [porraceous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/porraceous#:%7E:text=%3A%20having%20the%20clear%20light%20green%20color%20of%20leek%20leaves) plant.—בורית כ׳ an alkaline solution of carshina. [Ker. 6ᵃ](https://www.sefaria.org/Keritot.6a.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [Y. Yoma IV, 41ᵈ](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Yoma.4.5.2?lang=bi).—Pl. כַּרְשִׁינִים, כַּרְשִׁינִין. [Sabb. I, 5 (17ᵇ)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shabbat.1.5?lang=bi) אין שורין … וכ׳ אלא וכ׳ (shortly before Sabbath) we must not lay in ink-material, … or alkaline plants; [comment. refer to next w.].
>
> **II** כַּרְשִׁינָה, (כַּרְשִׁינָא III) f. (cmp. כַּרְשִׁינָא I) a **[species of vetch](https://www.britannica.com/plant/vetch)**, prob. horse-bean, rarely used as human food. [Bekh. VI, 1 (37ᵃ)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Bekhorot.6.1?lang=bi) ניקבה מלא כ׳ if there is a hole in the ear lap of the size of a carshinah; [Bekh. 37ᵇ](https://www.sefaria.org/Bekhorot.37b.16?lang=bi), expl. הינדא; [Tosef. ib. IV, 1.](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Bekhorot.4.1?lang=bi) [Y. Kidd. I, 59ᵈ](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Kiddushin.1.2.29?lang=bi) top פחות מן הכ׳ less than the size of &c.; a. e.—Pl. כַּרְשִׁינִים, כַּרְשִׁינִין. [B. Mets. 90ᵃ](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.90a.13?lang=bi). [Ḥall. IV, 9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Challah.4.9?lang=bi), a. fr. כַּרְשִׁינֵי תרומה beans set aside for the priest’s share. [Maas. Sh. II, 4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Maaser_Sheni.2.4?lang=bi); [Tosef. ib. II, 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Maaser_Sheni.2.1?lang=bi). [Y. Ḥall. IV, 60ᵇ](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Challah.4.4.20?lang=bi) אימתי גזרו על הכ׳ (contrad. to בִּיקְיָא) when was the law declaring carshinah subject to T’rumah enacted?—Answ. בימי רעבון in days of famine (when it served as human food). [Esth. R. to I, 14](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther_Rabbah.4.2?lang=bi) (play on כ̇ר̇ש̇נ̇א, ib.) אני בוזק לפניהם כ̇ר̇שׁינ̇ין ומש̇ירן מן העולם I shall crush vetch (to be placed) before them (send a famine compelling them to eat vetch) and make them fall off (fade away) from the world. [Y. Maas. Sh. II, 53ᶜ](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Maaser_Sheni.2.2.1?lang=bi) קל … בכרשיני (read: בכרשינין) they made the law concerning carsh. less stringent. [Ib](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.2a?lang=bi). עיסה של כ׳ a dough made of c.—[Meïl. III, 6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Meilah.3.6?lang=bi) כרשיני הקדש; Tosef. ib. I, 21 כַּרְשִׁנֵּי ed. Zuck. (some ed. כר שני, corr. acc.), v. הֶקְדֵּשׁ; a. fr.—[Koh. R. to VI, 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Kohelet_Rabbah.6.1.1?lang=bi) כַּרְשִׁנִּים בפלפלין he who puts vetch into pepper; ([Tosef. B. Bath. V](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Bava_Batra.6?lang=bi), 6 כּוּסְבֶּרֶת).

Comment: Rashi kerisus 6A says two pshatim. One of them clearly says it’s a place. כרשינא - הבא מאותו מקום so while @shalom is discussing the second pshat of rashi, the OP obviously was asking according to the first. Rabbeinu Gershom and other Rishonim say it’s the name of a place as well